# Two adjectives of a single noun

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

> She is the best and wisest girl in the class.
>
> She is the best and the wisest girl in the class.

Which one of them is correct?and why?
I think first one should be correct as both the adjectives are for one common noun? My book says second is correct.I am confused.
Please shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

this is an article usage, mainly.(the)

> She is *the* **best** and *the* **wisest** girl in the class.

From the ground rule of article usage, 'the'+adjective is used if the adjective in a sentence is in superlative form. For example:

> - The best
>
>   - The baddest
>   - The worst
>   - The richest
> - The wisest

Your rule book is right, stick into it. The **best** and the **wisest** in the class, means amongst other students in the class she is the **best**(superlative) and the **wisest**(superlative). Alrighty?
On the other hand, if you are referring to the 'best and wisest' it is another topic, because there are common 'set phrases' such as 'the best and cheap cellphone' as you can see 'cheap' is not in superlative form here.

Further, if you see some sentences with 'the best and (adjective)... -they are mostly set phrases or idioms, so, they are **exception** to the rule of *article usage*

Answer (score 0):

Strictly according to rules the second is correct:

- She is the best and the wisest girl in the class.

However, the first example of usage appear quite often too and seems not to be incorrect either.

Comment: what is the rule?

Comment: For a bit more info, when reading the second one, I pronounce "the" as "THEE" which emphatically states she by far "the wisest" person in class.  Otherwise, seeing the article repeated is ever so slightly awkward to my native ear.  There is also a colloquial phrase "best and brightest" that comes to mind instead of "best and wisest" .